# How to create a ParquetFile object from a Table (or Dataset) in Pyarrrow

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I have access to a `Dataset` or `Table`

```
ds = pyarrow.dataset.dataset(PARQUET_FILE_PATH, filesystem=fs)
table = ds.to_table()
```

I need to get the parquet metadata, which is only available through `ParquetFile`. Tried the following but failed with an error:  `AttributeError: type object 'ParquetFile' has no attribute 'from_table'`

```
pq_file_from_table = pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.from_table(table)
file_meta: FileMetaData = pq_file_from_table.metadata
```

Comment: why not read metadata directly from `PARQUET_FILE_PATH` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest ParquetFile doesn't work with ADLS Gen2 natively. The ability to  submit a custom filesystem is only available sine 11.0  version.

Comment: Do you need just column names/types or extended metadata info like `total_byte_size`, `compression` etc. ?

Comment: Extended metadata. Basically the following objects:  Statistics, ParquetSchema, FileMetaData, ColumnChunkMetaData

Comment: `ParquetFile` constructor accepts a `file-like object`. You could try awork around by doing something like `file = fs.open(PARQUET_FILE_PATH); parquet_file = ParquetFIle(file)`.